# Include subfolders as separate layers in docker image

Tags: docker, copy, layer

I have a fairly large docker image +- 500mb. Where most of the size comes from jpeg and png images. And the problem is that if I change one tiny thing inside a source file somewhere, then the entire image is rebuilt, pushed, and pulled online. This slows down deployment and testing quite a bit as our network is not very fast. At this point we mostly do source code changes and we don't update the jpeg and png images. So it's kind of pointless to upload all of them every time we do a source code patch.

So what I want to do is first add the jpeg and png images in a layer, and then the rest of the source code. So technically the SHA hashes should remain the same until beyond the jpeg and png image layer when normal source code changes are made, thus the jpeg and png images should not be re-uploaded when I push to the repo. But the nature of the folder structure doesn't really allow for this to be done easily, and changing the folder structure to make it easy at this point is not an option either as there are too many internal links and external links floating around the web.

So the copy commands form the Dockerfile currently looks like so:

```
COPY projectname/web_main/ projectname/web_main/
COPY projectname/web_lib/ projectname/web_lib/
```

But the images that I want to copy FIRST as a separate layer resides in:

```
projectname/web_main/net/www/assets
projectname/web_lib/img
```

So the images are sub folders deep inside the rest of the code. So technically what I am planning to do is something like so:

```
# Stage 1 Copy
COPY projectname/web_main/net/www/assets projectname/web_main/net/www/assets
COPY projectname/web_lib/img projectname/web_lib/img

# Stage 2 Copy
COPY projectname/web_main/ projectname/web_main/
COPY projectname/web_lib/ projectname/web_lib/
```

But obviously stage 2 should copy everything except what was copied in stage 1. So how do I write stage 2 to ignore the files copied in stage 1 already?

Answer (score 0):

You could build these as two separate images. So create one Dockerfile for your Stage 1, then another for Stage 2 that uses (`FROM stage1`). Use a .dockerignore file to have the second stage ignore the files from Stage 1. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-dockerignore-file

From the link:

> When using the BuildKit backend, docker build searches for a .dockerignore file relative to the Dockerfile name. For example, running docker build -f myapp.Dockerfile . will first look for an ignore file named myapp.Dockerfile.dockerignore. If such a file is not found, the .dockerignore file is used if present. Using a Dockerfile based .dockerignore is useful if a project contains multiple Dockerfiles that expect to ignore different sets of files.

If you are not using BuildKit, then I suppose you could probably do something in your build script like: Build Stage 1, write the .dockerignore, Build Stage 2.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The platform that we use doesn't have the ability to have a per project .dockerignore file. You can pretty much only declare a Dockerfile, and that's it. From the lack of other answers it seems like it's the only way. I will see if I can swap the .dockerignore file in and out quickly before and after build using scripts. Not an elegant solution, but it would work for now.